# Filling multiple objects in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

i try fill two objects in two other forms.And in controller i just print these objects.
my code:
controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mvcaddDevice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addDevice(
        @ModelAttribute("deviceType") DeviceTypeDTO dt,
        @ModelAttribute("marka") MarkaDTO marka,
        ModelMap model
) {
    System.out.println("you send deveiceType=" + dt);
    System.out.println("you send marka=" + marka);
    model.addAttribute("dt", dt);
    model.addAttribute("marka", marka);
    return "result";
}
```

view:

```
            <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="windows-1252"%>
            <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
                    <title>JSP Page</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h2>${message}</h2>
                    <img src="assets/goodboy.jpg"/>
                    <form:form method="POST" 
                               action="/mvcaddDevice"  
                               commandName="deviceType"
                               modelAttribute="deviceType"
                               >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><form:label path="order">order</form:label></td>
                                <td><form:input path="order" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Add device type"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>  
                    </form:form>

                    <form:form 
                        method="POST" 
                        action="/mvcaddDevice" 
                        commandName="marka" 
                        modelAttribute="marka"
                        >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><form:label path="markaName">Name</form:label></td>
                                <td><form:input path="markaName"  /></td>
                                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Add marka"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>  
                    </form:form>
                </body >
            </html>
```

in controller method we have @ModelAttribute("deviceType") DeviceTypeDTO dt and @ModelAttribute("marka") MarkaDTO marka .These means which object will be related to dt and marka instances .in first form i fill deviceType fields and in second form i fill marka fields. when i press first submit these fields will go to dt(because of modelAttribute="deviceType"). when i press second submit these fields will go to marka.(because of modelAttribute="marka") @ModelAttribute is using for decision which form will be mapped to which object.But it doesnt work.
i need same method but for 2 objects.so i dont want to write same method 2 times

Output:

```
Info:   you send deveiceType=DeviceTypeDTO{name=test, order=0}
Info:   you send marka=MarkaDTO{markaName=null, name=test}
```

what is the reason ? how can i solve it?

Comment: Are you asking how to handle multiple forms in one page?

Comment: i want to handle each form by same controller method.when i post first form this will go first modelattribute, and when i click on second form this will go second modelattribute.but one name field is filling on each object though i click on first form

Comment: Do you mean *using a same method* for 2 different requests??

Comment: i need same method but for 2 objects.which object is different from null i will do method for that object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @ModelAttribute is using for decision which form will be mapped to which object.

No. If you declare a bean as a model attribute Spring MVC will create the Model attribute for you. It will populate the attributes from the request.

When you submitted the first form, with **modelAttribute="deviceType"** the Controller method will still create 2 model objects, because the two were marked as @ModelAttribute. While creating the MarkaDTO object, it would be able to match the name field, because it was in the request body. But markaName was not in request so that is null.

I agree with @ck1 suggestions.

Comment: thanks for reply.And how can i do my aim?mapping forms to specific object in one method for avoiding declare the same method twice

Comment: Since you have two forms, it would be better design to have a Controller method for each. If the purpose is similar, you can reuse the business logic inside the two methods by calling the same processing method in them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do here, but I believe what makes the most sense is for you to either:

1) Consolidate your two forms into a single form, with a single `@RequestMapping` method in your controller, and a single DTO object; or

2) Define two separate `@RequestMapping` methods in your controller, one per form.

Comment: in controller method we have @ModelAttribute("deviceType") DeviceTypeDTO dt and @ModelAttribute("marka") MarkaDTO marka
.These means which object will be related to dt and marka instances
.in first form i fill deviceType fields and in second form i fill marka fields.
when i press first submit these fields will go to dt(because of modelAttribute="deviceType").
when i press second submit these fields will go to marka.(because of modelAttribute="marka")

@ModelAttribute is using for decision which form will be mapped to which object.But it doesnt work

Comment: i need same method but for 2 objects.so i dont want to write same method 2 times